# Save changes in database using BindingSource

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I retrieve data from database like this:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter 
            = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * "
              + " FROM myTab1, myTab2"
              + " WHERE myTab1.col1 = myTab2.col3"
              , connection);//OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("myDataTable");
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Then I use `bindingSource` in order to access the data in my program, everything works perfect. But after all changes I've made in `bindingSource`, I need so save them into the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well normally you'd call `Update()` on the `DataAdapter`:

```
dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

But since your query "joins" two tables it may not be so easy.  It may be possible if you turn your `SELECT` query into a proper join:

```
  "SELECT * "
+ "FROM myTab1 "
+ "JOIN myTab2 ON myTab1.col1 = myTab2.col3"
```

Some other alternatives:

- Write an UPDATE statement that will put the right values in the right tables and set your `dataAdapter`'s `UpdateStatement`
- Populate the dataset with separate tables (one per base table) and join in your app

More info from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @D Stanley, could you explain to me how to populate the dataset with separate tables in my case, using my data, that would be very helpful

Comment: Fill the DataSet with two different `Fill` commands: `SELECT * FROM myTab1` and `SELECT * FROM myTab2`.  Then add a `DataRelation` to the `DataSet`.